# Ensuring exact same coordinate returned by calculation

Tags: javascript, svg, geometry, precision

I have placed 4 smaller circles on a big circle at `0, 90, 180, 270` degree angle. I expect javascript to return *exact same*  `y` for red and blue circle (as the shift is horizontal, y is the same but x changes) and  *exact same*  `x` for green and pink circle (as the shift is vertical, x is the same but y changes).

While the below the javascript returns the same x but returns different y (red = 237.76900370542438 and blue = 237.7690037054244). Moving forward, it is messing up all the calculations since they are not the same.

I don't know what is the root cause of this but is there a way to solve it? I need them to be exact same.

```js
const angle = [0, 90, 180, 270];
const angleCoord = [];

angle.forEach(
    (a, i) => {
        const element = d3.select('.circ1').node();
        const cx = parseFloat(element.getAttribute('cx'));
        const cy = parseFloat(element.getAttribute('cy'));
        const r = parseFloat(element.getAttribute('r'));
        const x = cx + Math.cos(a * Math.PI / 180) * r;
        const y = cy + Math.sin(a * Math.PI / 180) * r;
        angleCoord.push({
            angle: a,
            x: x,
            y: y
        })
    }
);

const color = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'pink'];

d3.select('svg').append('g')
    .attr('class', 'circles')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(angleCoord)
    .join('circle')
    .attr('class', (_, i) => color[i])
    .attr('cx', d => d.x)
    .attr('cy', d => d.y)
    .attr('r', '4')
    .attr('fill', (_, i) => color[i]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bignumber.js@9.1.2/bignumber.min.js'></script>
  <body>
    <div id="container" class="svg-container"></div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1536 720">
      <circle class="circ1" cx="384" cy="237.76900370542438" r="122.23099629457562" fill="none" stroke="black"></circle>
    </svg>
    <script src="prod3.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "_it is messing up all the calculations since they are not the same._" > Please give an example of a "messed up calculation" that is caused by this.  Also please read:  [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1563833)

Comment: JavaScript and floats aren't the greatest, do: ``console.log( 0.1 + 0.2 )`` So you have some work to do to be "the same" in JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Wyck for sharing the link which led to another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67986995/11156131).

I was able to adapt the suggestions from this link and use it in the above case to resolve the issue by letting js take care of it within the code.

```js
const angle = [0, 90, 180, 270];
const angleCoord = [];
const color = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'pink'];

function round(value, precision) {
  const power = Math.pow(10, precision)
  return Math.round((value*power)+(Number.EPSILON*power)) / power
}

angle.forEach(
    (a, i) => {
        const element = d3.select('.circ1').node();
        const cx = round(parseFloat(element.getAttribute('cx')),15);
        const cy = round(parseFloat(element.getAttribute('cy')),15);
        const r = round(parseFloat(element.getAttribute('r')),15);
        const _sin = round(Math.sin(a * Math.PI / 180),15);
        const _cos = round(Math.cos(a * Math.PI / 180),15);
        const x = cx + _cos * r;
        const y = cy + _sin * r;
        
        console.log(`${color[i]}`,cx,cy,r,_sin,_cos,x,y,);
        
        angleCoord.push({
            angle: a,
            x: x,
            y: y
        })
    }
);

d3.select('svg').append('g')
    .attr('class', 'circles')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(angleCoord)
    .join('circle')
    .attr('class', (_, i) => color[i])
    .attr('cx', d => d.x)
    .attr('cy', d => d.y)
    .attr('r', '4')
    .attr('fill', (_, i) => color[i]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bignumber.js@9.1.2/bignumber.min.js'></script>
  <body>
    <div id="container" class="svg-container"></div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1536 720">
      <circle class="circ1" cx="384" cy="237.76900370542438" r="122.23099629457562" fill="none" stroke="black"></circle>
    </svg>
    <script src="prod3.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The accuracy of sin 180 is about as accurate as the accuracy of PI/2 plus or minus some infinitesimal error.

Consider using the "exact" values for sin and cos of the multiples of 90° angles in degrees if you want "exact" values.  e.g.:

```
const lookupTable = {
  0: { sin: 0, cos: 1 },
  90: { sin: 1, cos: 0 },
  180: { sin: 0, cos: -1 },
  270: { sin: -1, cos: 0 }
};

const exactSin = degrees => lookupTable[degrees].sin;
const exactCos = degrees => lookupTable[degrees].cos;
```

```js
const angle = [0, 90, 180, 270];
const angleCoord = [];

const lookupTable = {
  0: { sin: 0, cos: 1 },
  90: { sin: 1, cos: 0 },
  180: { sin: 0, cos: -1 },
  270: { sin: -1, cos: 0 }
};

const exactSin = (degrees) => lookupTable[degrees].sin;
const exactCos = (degrees) => lookupTable[degrees].cos;

angle.forEach(
    (a, i) => {
        const element = d3.select('.circ1').node();
        const cx = parseFloat(element.getAttribute('cx'));
        const cy = parseFloat(element.getAttribute('cy'));
        const r = parseFloat(element.getAttribute('r'));
        const x = cx + exactCos(a) * r;
        const y = cy + exactSin(a) * r;
console.log({x, y});
        angleCoord.push({
            angle: a,
            x: x,
            y: y
        })
    }
);

const color = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'pink'];

d3.select('svg').append('g')
    .attr('class', 'circles')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(angleCoord)
    .join('circle')
    .attr('class', (_, i) => color[i])
    .attr('cx', d => d.x)
    .attr('cy', d => d.y)
    .attr('r', '4')
    .attr('fill', (_, i) => color[i]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bignumber.js@9.1.2/bignumber.min.js'></script>
  <body>
    <div id="container" class="svg-container"></div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1536 720">
      <circle class="circ1" cx="384" cy="237.76900370542438" r="122.23099629457562" fill="none" stroke="black"></circle>
    </svg>
    <script src="prod3.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any other way to handle this within the code; other than using a hardcoded look-up table. Cause, for the prod, I would not know all the angles beforehand (cause they are all dynamic), therefore it won't be possible to build a table as such.

Comment: Other angles won't be exact.  Is it axial *symmetry* that you're looking for?  Just compute all your angles in one quadrant and then rotate them into the other quadrants using the above lookup tables.

Comment: @smpa01 please update your question to define your requirements more clearly with respect what you want your results to be when _all the angles are dynamic_.